# nodejs express sent object not synchronized with front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send an object from nodejs server to the front end but one property is keep getting deleted on the way

server

```
router.post('/cart/retrieve', (req, res) => {
    let cart = req.session.cart;
    let prodId = Object.keys(cart);

    Product.find({_id: {$in: prodId}}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let resultToSend = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            let curResult = result[i];

            curResult['cartQuantity'] = parseInt(cart[curResult._id]);
            result[i] = curResult;
        }
        resultToSend = result;

        console.log(resultToSend[0]['cartQuantity'])

        res.json({cart: resultToSend})
    });
});
```

frontend

```
$("#top-cart-trigger").click(function(e){
    $.post('/api/shop/cart/retrieve',{

    }, function (returnResult) {
        console.log(returnResult['cart'][0]['cartQuantity'])
        let products = returnResult['cart'];
        console.log(returnResult)
        for(let i = 0; i < products.length; i ++){
            let curProduct = products[i];
            console.log(curProduct['cartQuantity'])
        }
    });

});
```

so practically the json variable sent from server and the `returnResult` received from the front end are same variables. However, my `console.log(resultToSend[0]['cartQuantity'])` returns 3 (which is correct) but `console.log(curProduct['cartQuantity'])` is undefined for all elements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note (it's not the problem): The `result[i] = curResult;` in the loop is completely pointless. So is the `= []` on your `let resultToSend = [];`, since you just overwrite it with `result` later. (The whole `resultToSend` variable serves no purpose in that code, in fact.)

Comment: Try it like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/qcdmv9vk/ , `product` is most likely a cursor, and not what you should be editing

Comment: What are the things in `result`? If, for instance, the entries are arrays, adding a non-element property to them will work but that property won't be serialized to JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yea I know. I was consoling out every single line to see where the problem might be that's why I changed the code like this but thank you for pointing out

Comment: @adeneo it didn't solve it unfortunately

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the contents of result is an array of objects. It retrieves product results from mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might comes from mutable variable `result` in your server.

However it seems like the variable `returnResult['cart']` is JSON and you are expecting array. You could use 'for in' instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Just try to replace for loop with this

```
   for (let key in returnResult['cart']){
        console.log(returnResult['cart'][key]['cartQuantity']);
    }
```